# subprocess not work in django with apache

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This probelm confused me many days, i can't figure it out, please help.

windows django 1.7.8 + python 2.7.8
requirment: copy file to s3 with aws cli

```
process  = subprocess.Popen( r'C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\aws.exe s3 cp e:\test\p001.zip  s3://bucketsname',stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

This code can be successful in A,B,C, and file copied to s3.

**A.** run in directly in python cmd

**B.** run in python manage.py shell

**C.** run in django default http server

**D.** django + apache wsgi

The only problem is that D, if i use apache in django, the cmd not work, file not copied. 
So how to deal with apache in this case?  Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing the apache process serving your request dies taking your s3 copy-process with it, but there really isn't enough info in your question to say -- e.g. what's in your log files, what are the error messages, where's the rest of your code (you have to join with the process, right)?

Comment: In all these "many days" of working on this, why didn't you even try to use boto as I previously recommended? You really won't ever get anywhere by trying to do things like this.

Comment: Hi Daniel, i tried boto, but not success in python, so i switch back to aws cli.

Comment: From python run boto:
raise BotoServerError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request

Comment: Hi thebjorn. i just got  return code is 1. I have no idea why it doesn't work with apache.
 From s3 doc, "return code 1 -- Limited to s3 commands, at least one or more s3 transfers failed for the command executed."

Comment: From apache error log, i got new clue, "upload failed  Unable to locate credential", looks like the apache not find the aws cli configure file.

Answer (score 1):

Find the root reason: Apache can't load the aws cli configure file, actually it is exists there. "aws configure list" can show correct. So manually set the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in system var. Thank you all!